# AEM - Inheriting/extending the fields in dialog

Tags: aem

0
I want to extend the fields in one dialog to another. Just did the googling and found out that we can use the xtype as **cqinclude** and path as "**apps\myproject\dialog\tab2.infinity.json**"
This helps to extend the tabs, but i would like to extend the widgets in the same tab not as a separate tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same process can be used for individual items: just set a particular widget to `cqinclude` and extend the path down to the individual widget level too, e.g.

`apps/myproject/dialog/tab2/items/items/firstpanel/items/title.infinity.json`

Would then include the `cq:Widget` **title**.